# Getting started with Django

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I want to develop my application using google app engine into which I will use python. Now after wondering I came to know it is good it I use dJango template.

**Does anyone can tell me or suggest me what to refer to start with Django because from tutorial on its website, it looks difficult?**

Comment: the " getting started tutorial " on django website looked realy easy to mee , it get's you up and running in no time at all , if you find it dificult to follow you can allways start small and play with python a bit for start , get familiar with the sintax and everithing .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to make things more complicated, but you will also need to consider issues specific to running Django on GAE.

It is not as simple as just running the latest Django on GAE.  Django is moving towards native support for GAE (and for NoSQL databases in general) but they aren't quite there yet.

I would suggest you look at this article:
"Running Pure Django Projects on Google App Engine"
http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/django-nonrel.html

This way of using Django on GAE (via the django-nonrel project) seems to be the preferred way.

Answer (score 0):

Once more I can recommend a [gigantuan.net](http://gigantuan.net). For me, nothing works better than video tutorials. On Gigantuan you can find 8 movies which will help you to understand the basics of django by building a blog site. Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

I've also recently started with Django, and I would recommend reading "behind" the tutorial - if you look at the docs as a whole at http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ then you can read up more on the bits you are stuck on.

I've found the documentation as a whole is excellent.  There's even a book on http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/ which will give you some slightly different examples from the tutorial.